# Terms of Service Content Locker

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a piece of code that will pop-up on a wordpress blog that displays my terms of service, and in order to view the content of the page, they will need to hit "I Accept". I've looked for some wordpress plugin solutions, but none of them work the way I want them to.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This plugin will solve your problem - [**Content Warning**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-warning-v2/).

Using Ajax & Thickbox, the content warning box shows a message to users with the option to enter or leave the site.

Install the plugin and goto plugin settings and Enable it.

Update the ENTER and EXIT text to ACCEPT and DECLINE. Also in the Message box add your terms of service.

Cheers !!!